# Kernel of $\pi_{m-1}(SO_m) \to \pi_{m-1}(SO_{m+1})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles

There is an inclusion map $i: SO_m \to SO_{m+1}$ and this induces a homomorphism

$$i_* : \pi_{m-1}(SO_m) \to \pi_{m-1}(SO_{m+1})$$

Now we can think of $\pi_{m-1}(SO_m)$, via the clutching functions, as the set of $m$-bundles over $S^m$.  I happen to have an $m$-bundle over $S^m$ that I like, namely the tangent bundle $T^m$; let's call $[T] \in \pi_{m-1}(SO_m)$ the corresponding element.

Why is $\ker(i_*)$ generated by $[T]$?

Comment: $[T]$ lies in the kernel since $TS^{m-1}\oplus\nu$ is trivial ($\nu$ is the rank 1 real normal bundle of the standard embedding $S^{m-1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$). You can use characteristic classes to rule out $[T]$ being a sum of other generators.